# Im getting an error in youtube-dl options saying 'invalid syntax'

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-dl

So I am getting this error in youtube-dl options saying invalid syntax. Here's my code:

```
ydl_opts = {
            'outtmpl': 'music/song.mp3'
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
```

and here is my error:

```
  File "C:\Users\nuk\Desktop\projects\YTQuizBot\main.py", line 89
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing  `,`  after 'outtmpl': 'music/song.mp3',

```
ydl_opts = {
            'outtmpl': 'music/song.mp3',
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
```